# gnome-terminal title appears and disappears via bash

Tags: gnome-terminal

My bash script works fine and also sets the tile of my terminal.
However , the titles disappears once all commands are executed.
Heres by script.

```
#!/bin/sh
gnome-terminal  --tab -t 'My Title' -e '/bin/bash -c "cd /home/user/MY_FOLDER; ssh user@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -i my_pem_file.pem;bash" '
```

Any suggestions please

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/profile` sources `/etc/profile.d/vte-2.91.sh` which in turn sets up your `$PROMPT_COMMAND` to print two things: set the title (inlined in `__vte_prompt_command`) and set the concept of the current working directory, in order to be able to open a new terminal there (from `__vte_prompt_command` it's the last `%s` in the format string, and the corresponding call to `__vte_osc7`).

What I do in order to get rid of the former, yet keep the latter, is that in my `~/.bashrc` I have this snippet:

```
. /etc/profile.d/vte-2.91.sh
if [ -n "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ]; then
    PROMPT_COMMAND='__vte_osc7'
fi
```

(It would probably be nicer to place it in `~/.profile` instead, and probably you could omit the first line as well as the `if` guard then. Up to you to experiment with this.)

Note: This overall design sucks and we have a bug to clean this up: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=704960

Comment: Didnt have a file called vte-2.91.sh. Created one and placed the code there. didnt work for me

Comment: Probably you have a `vte.sh` then, in case your Ubuntu is older. Leave those files under `/etc/profile.d` untouched, add the snipped I showed to `~/.bashrc` (with obvious adjustment of the filename it refers to).